# Missing Parentheses make problem confusing

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem for a job interview. It is a multiple choice question. The question asks us to rewrite the expression $\frac{1}{3}x^2-2$ as $\frac{1}{3}(x+k)(x-k)$ and to give the value of $k$. The four choices are 2, 6, $\sqrt{2}$, and $\sqrt{6}$.

I thought difference of squares and so thought $\sqrt{2}$. But now I am not so sure. Shouldn't the expression be written as $\frac{1}{3}(x^2-2)$, with parentheses around the $x^2-2$ part? What is the justification for not treating the first term of the equation as $\frac{1}{3}x^2$ instead of as $x^2$? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Use the distributive property of multiplication. What do you get when you multiply out $\frac{1}{3}(x^2-2)$. Do you get $\frac{1}{3}x^2-2$? How do you change $\frac{1}{3}(x^2-2)$ so that you get $\frac{1}{3}x^2-2$ when you multiply it out.

Comment: Thanks, I see now.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there.

$$\frac{1}{3}x^2 - 2 = \frac{1}{3}(x^2-6)$$

and now you can apply the same strategy you used earlier.

Alternatively, you can compare coefficients: $\frac{1}{3}x^2 - 2 = \frac{1}{3}(x+k)(x-k)$, so $x^2 - 6 = (x+k)(x-k) \Rightarrow x^2-6 = x^2-k^2$. This means that $k^2 = 6$ therefore $k = \sqrt{6}, -\sqrt{6}$. Both are correct, but only $\sqrt{6}$ is in the answer choices.

Comment: So that would imply that the answer to the question is $\sqrt{6}$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is precisely what the problem wants to test. Compute:
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{3}x^2 - 2 &= \frac{1}{3}(x^2 - 6) 
\\&= \frac{1}{3}(x + \sqrt 6)(x - \sqrt 6)\end{align},$$
so the answer is $k = \sqrt 6$.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Thank you. This is what other people were trying to tell me but that I was too dense to see.

Answer (score 2):

$ \frac{1}{3}x^2-2=\frac{1}{3}(x^2-6),$ hence $k= \sqrt{6}.$

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking nearly correctly.  Rewrite like this:

$$\frac{1}{3}x^2 - \frac{1}{3}6 = \frac{1}{3}(x^2-6).$$

Now the parens are where you need them.

Comment: So am I understanding you correctly? When they write in the question $\frac{1}{3}x^2 - 2$ I should understand them to be saying $\frac{1}{3}(x^2 - 6)$?

Comment: Not "understanding them to be saying", but "it's equivalent to."    But since this is a multiple choice question, you can just plug in  each of the choices for $k$ and see which one works.